# Failed to resolve directive: scroll-to Vue-scrollto

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, scroll

I am making a web application with Vue js(i am a newbie on vue js), specifically Vue 2.x. I want to click in an element of a menu, and then scroll to the that element. I have thought to use this tool https://vue-scrollto.netlify.app/examples/ as it is exactly what i want to do.

The problem is that when I repeat the same the code as in the examples, I receive the error "**[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: scroll-to**". Here is my code:

```html
<div :class="{subelementos: isOpenAndroid}">
        <div class="subelementos2">
          <p v-scroll-to="'#prueba'" class="subelementos3" @click="menuClick('android')">Principios</p>

        </div>
</div>
```

And then in another component:

```html
<div id="prueba">
      <p>TEXTEXT</p>
</div>
```

I don't know if someone is familiar with this tool. I think i am missing something important.

PS: Maybe is a stupid question(sorry about that) but, do you think is mandatory to use Nuxtjs? On the official page of the tool it is mentioned, but I think is optional https://vue-scrollto.netlify.app/docs/#nuxt-js.

----EDIT----

The HTML, CSS and JS are in the same file, specifically on a .vue file. I think that maybe I have to import an external library into my .vue file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you haven't registered the directive.

The `vue-scrollto` docs describe [how to setup the directive](https://vue-scrollto.netlify.app/docs/#as-a-vue-directive). The plugin automatically registers the directive under the hood, and you can install the plugin in your app's entry point with [`Vue.use()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-use):

```js
// main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueScrollTo from 'vue-scrollto'

Vue.use(VueScrollTo)
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vue-scroll-to?file=src%2Fmain.js)

Comment: Great!! I have to say that I tried that before, but on my component(on the .vue file), so it didn't work there. But now, I added to the main.js file and it works. Thanks ;)